# MODx Revo не выводится то, что написано в дополнительном поле (TV)

Tags: modx, revo

Создал tv с названием "formImage" (картинка) и "formSize" (текст). В параметрах вывода указал тег li с классом "form-class". В шаблоне прописал:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`[[*id]]` &tpl=`form`]]
```

В чанке form:

```
[[*formImage]]
[[*formSize]]
```

На странице сайта выводится пустой тег li с классом "form-class". Картинка выбрана и в текстовом поле есть текст, но они почему-то не отображаются на сайте. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы уменьшить время поиска, getResources не показывает TV значения по умолчанию. Если вы хотите отобразить TV, вы должны включить следующие параметры:

```
&includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1`
```

Кроме того, необходимо добавлять префикс ко всем TV. или использовать этот параметр удаляющий префикс:

```
&tvPrefix=``
```

В чанках шаблонах вывода следует использовать TV c префиксом tv (если это не отменено способом выше):

```
[[+tv.my_tv]]
```

взято с: http://minyta.ru/modx/snippet/getresources.html

Comment: Благодарю! Эта рекомендация помогла, все данные вывелись.